# Creating a script to replicate webs from csv file

Tags: bash

I have created a bash script to read from csv and create webpages but I soon as I have one error the script stops, how can avoid the script exit if I have any error?

Comment: Hi there! Can you please post your scripts so we can help you?

Comment: Any info to how to do it?

Comment: # Sustituir Base de datos
   cd /var/www/html/$URL/public_html/script
  
   php srdb.cli.php -h localhost -n "wp_$mod" -usa -pCasala33 -s http://farmacia-demo.com -r "http://$URL" --v false
   #php srdb.cli.php -h localhost -n "wp_$mod" -usa -pCasala33 -s @farmacia-demo.com -r "@$URL" -v true
   #php srdb.cli.php -h localhost -n "wp_$mod" -usa -pCasala33 -s Farmacia_Demo -r "$NOMBRE" -v true
   #chown -R www-data /var/www/html/$URL/public_html
   #chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html/$URL/public_html
   systemctl reload apache2

Comment: This is the part of script where I have problems, I made a call to other script (php plugin of wordpress) and always finalize there...

Comment: [edit] your question to include your code, don't put it in a comment where you can't format it and so it appears as a monolithic line of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `set -e` and [never use it](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).